# Nginx + php5-fpm + node.js

Tags: php, node.js, nginx

## Solved

I had a problem in my nginx conf file.

Code `location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$` is most specific match, so I had change the line:

```
location /node/
```

to:

```
location ^~ /node/
```

and now all is ok.

## Question

Firstly, apologize for my English.

I have problem with nginx and node.js, I want to serve all files with nginx, .php files with php5-fpm and files from domain.com/node/ with node.js
And my configuration do it, but I have problem with scripts in HTML documents e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/node/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

show me error 404, and node.js not serve this file.

This is my configuration:

```
server {
    server_name www.domain.com;
    listen 80;

    return 301 http://domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name domain.com;
    listen 80;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain_com_access_log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/domain_com_error_log;
    root       /home/domain_com/www;

    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$
    {
        expires max;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ /\.          { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
    location ~ ~$           { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }

    location ~ cache/(.*)$
    {
        deny all;
    }

    location /node/
    {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234/;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$
    {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-fpm_domain_com.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this file exist? `/home/domain_com/www/node/socket.io/socket.io.js` at this exact path ?

Comment: No, this file must be serve by node.js server.In 'node' folder i 'node_modules' folder, and node.js server should serve this file.

Comment: Then you need to remove the `try_files` line inside the `location /node`, because it makes nginx look for the file locally

Comment: Is there any local files inside `/node`?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I delete this line, but this still don't work. Inside /node is index.html and app.js and node_modules folder.

Comment: did you reload the nginx?

Comment: check if the error log says something different since we removed the `try_files`

Comment: I checked something else and it turned out that the .js files were not at all directed to node.js because "location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$". I add prefix "^~" to location /node/ and now is all ok.